# GCE Windows Server gets auto shut down

Tags: google-compute-engine

My Windows Server instance on GCE is shut down from time to time. Based on the GCP logging, we can tell that fail to pass the lateBootReportEvent check only triggers a reboot by a certain chance. I am wondering why?

```
logs screenshot
```

[image: logs_screenshot]

I am aware that auto-shutdown is caused by integrity monitoring (settings shown below). And I understand that my boot integrity might fail here. I am just trying to understand why there is a "probability" here

```
Shielded-VM settings
```

[image: Shielded-VM settings]

Answer (score 0):

The integrity monitor and shielded VMs don't have any relation with a VM restart or shutdown.

[Integrity monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/security/shielded-cloud/shielded-vm#integrity-monitoring) only compares the most recent boot measurements to the integrity policy baseline and returns a pair of pass/fail results depending on whether they match or not, one for the early boot sequence and one for the late boot sequence.

Early boot is the boot sequence from the start of the UEFI firmware until it passes control to the bootloader. Late boot is the boot sequence from the bootloader until it passes control to the operating system kernel. If either part of the most recent boot sequence doesn't match the baseline, you get an integrity validation failure.

If the failure is expected, for example if you applied some system update on that VM instance, you should update the integrity policy baseline. If it is not expected, you should stop that VM instance and investigate the reason for the failure, but the VM never be shutdown by integrity monitor .

In order to determine what actually caused the VM to restart you will need to look at the internal Windows event manager logs, and review the event viewer logs for the instance at time to shutdown, [then reference the shutdown reason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/system-shutdown-reason-codes) against Microsoft's reason codes to determine what caused the VM stop.

It is possible that the instance restarted to complete installation of updates, or encountered an [internal error](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#hosterror). However only the event viewer logs will determine the true cause.

If you found a useful internal logs please share on this post to check.